# Autosize column width using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am appending data to the existing excel using `POI`. But on appending the data, the excel headers which are already present before the editing are compressed to small areas. Can someone please suggest me how to avoid this? I have applied even `autoSize` after appending data, but of no use.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("dataexcel.xlsx"));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(intputStream);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowNum = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

                    int cellNum = 1;
                    Row lastRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

    for(int i =0 ; i<7; i++)
    {
                    Cell cell = lastRow.createCell(cellNum++);
                    cell.setCellValue(value);
                    cell.setCellStyle(generalStyle);
    }
```

Suppose the headers has a long text like `"This is very long text"` and appending the 7 values(2,3,1,7,4,6,5) to the existing excel in each cell to the next row like above. Then the enitre columns' widths shrink to the values of these single digits and the headers' text is almost invisible until it is expanded manually.

Answer (score 4):

Use `autoSizeColumn()` method?

Example Your Sheet as below

```
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D    |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
|   xxx    |    xxx   |This is very long text  |
|          |          |          |             |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

If so, make auto column size for `Column c`, `sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);`. Result will be

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+-------------+
| Column A | Column B | Column C               | Column D    |
+----------+----------+------------------------+-------------+
|   xxx    |    xxx   |This is very long text                |
|          |          |                        |             |
+----------+----------+------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question that I had used autosizeColumn, but didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Any update on this issue . I m using 3.10 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

POI 4.0: Try to call `sheet.autoSizeColumn(*)` after the calling all of `createCell` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue in Apache POI 3.9 and earlier. The problem is POI sets the column width to 0. Try updating to POI 3.10 and see if that solves your problem.

More info at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55644

Comment: This might be the issue, let me update to 3.10 and check. Thanks